# How to feed the shape to a placeholder which is changing every iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
char_id = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, word_max_len])
```

The shape of the `char_id` tensor should be `[current batch's vocab size * length of the biggest word in the current batch]`. Since I take different batch of sentences every iteration, the `vocab size` as well as the `length of biggest word in the batch` varies. I cannot use `None` for both fields in `shape`, because I later `unstack` and I get the error `Cannot infer num from shape`. I tried to feed the `word_max_len` as another placeholder and then use it in `char_id`, like this:

```
word_max_len = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=())
feed_dict = {char_id: char_id_batch, word_max_len: word_max_len_batch}
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I get the error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'`.

I do not want to have a large fixed `word_max_len`, say 100. I know it solves the problem, but I want to know how can I feed dynamically the shape for `char_id`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things going on in this question.

First, you cannot call int() on a Tensor because a Tensor doesn't have a value outside of the context of session.run.

Similarly, you can't unstack a tensor with unknown shape because it's not possible to determine how many output tensors the unstack op will have, so the result of the unstack will not be usable in the graph.

If you do want to do this I recommend building a separate graph for each batch size you care about, padding the batches with zeroes to keep the number of graphs small.